# Sort a file with a specific line pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

Given a file with the following content:

```
enum class Fruits(id: String) {
   BANANA(id = "banana"),
   LEMON(id = "lemon"),
   DRAGON_FRUIT(id = "dragonFruit"),
   APPLE(id = "apple"); }
```

I want to sort this file given the pattern "id = ", and then replace these lines with the new sorted lines.

I wrote a piece of code in python that sorts the whole file, but I'm struggling with regex to read/find the pattern so I can sort it.

My python script:

```
import re

fruitsFile = '/home/genericpath/Fruits.txt'

def sortFruitIds():

# this is an attempt to get/find the pattern, but it return an AttributeError: 
# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

    with open(fruitsFile, "r+") as f:
        lines = sorted(f, key=lambda line: str(re.search(r"(?<=id = )\s+", line)))
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
```

When trying to find the pattern with regex, it returns an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just provide all test data examples, or provide exact match specs.

Comment: `(?:(?<=id = )|(?<=id = \"))\S+|$`

Comment: You are a god on earth @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your main issue is that your regex expects a space character `\s` but what you want to be looking for is any non-space character `\S`. With that in mind this should work:

```py
import re

fruitsFile = 'Fruits.txt'

def sortFruitIds():

    with open(fruitsFile, "r+") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines_sorted = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: re.search(r"(?<=id = \")\S+|$", line).group())
        for line in lines_sorted:
            f.write(line)
```

I also added |$ to the regex to return an empty string if there is no match,  and added group() to grab the match.

Comment: For sure, also I'm not sure what your development situation looks like, but using a debugger can really help in these situations. I use Visual Studio Code's to solve your issue: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Comment: The potential problem with this approach is it is not the case that all lines should be sorted.  Only lines appearing inside the enum definition should be sorted.  The other ones should remain in place where they originally were (IIUC).

Comment: You are right @Tim, Ive noticed this problem but I didnt specified it on the question. Now im working on it.

Answer (score 1):

We can approach this by doing a regex find all for all entries in the enum.  Then sort them alphabetically by the `id` string value, and join together the final `enum` code.  Note that below I also extract the first line of the enum for use later in the output.

```py
inp = '''enum class Fruits(id: String) {
   BANANA(id = "banana"),
   LEMON(id = "lemon"),
   DRAGON_FRUIT(id = "dragonFruit"),
   APPLE(id = "apple"); }'''
header = re.search(r'enum.*?\{', inp).group()
items = re.findall(r'\w+\(id\s*=\s*".*?"\)', inp)
items.sort(key=lambda m: re.search(r'"(.*?)"', m).group(1))
output = header + '\n    ' + ',\n    '.join(items) + '; }'
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
enum class Fruits(id: String) {
    APPLE(id = "apple"),
    BANANA(id = "banana"),
    DRAGON_FRUIT(id = "dragonFruit"),
    LEMON(id = "lemon"); }
```